# Populating a Classes Variables using values from a split string

Tags: c#, string

So I have this code:

```
public class myClass
{

    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B{ get; set; }
    //and so on
}
```

I want to add a constructor that takes a string input and have that constructor split the string on ','then use the split values to populate the class variables

**What I Have Tried**

I have tried to make a string with my variables values like so:

```
public void myVoid()
    {


        string s = "A,B,..etc";
        string[] values = s.Split(',');

        foreach (string item in values)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

This returns my values one by one on each key press but this is just me getting my head around it.

So to clarify: I want to add a constructor that takes a string input and have that constructor split the string on ','then use the split values to populate the class variables

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? It looks like you have the core bits there already. You are already splitting the string you just need to assign the values to the appropriate properties.

Comment: Well i will be taking a CSV file, mainpulating it and output results into a width text file. Im just struggling a bit with the logic as i am still quite new to programming

I will be having a sit down soon to work out a clear work flow for the program and hopefully make things clear. Im taking all advice into consideration at this point

results to follow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
public class myClass
{
    public myClass(string input)
    {
         var ar = input.Split(',');
         if (ar.Length >= 2)
         {
             A = ar[0];
             B = ar[1];
         }
    }

    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B{ get; set; }
    //and so on
}
```

Use:

```
var myclass = new myClass("some,thing");
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i will be trying this and getting back to you as best i can

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach would be:

```
    public class myClass
    {
       public string A { get; set; }
       public string B{ get; set; }
       public myClass()
       {
         //default constructor
       }
       public myClass(string S)
       {
         string[] values = S.Split(',');
         if (values.Length>=2)
         {
            this.A=values[0];
            this.B=values[1];
         }
       }
     }
```

However your goal is a bit fuzzy. E.g which value of splited string would appended on A and which in B?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i will be trying this and getting back to you as best i can

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this -

```
public class myClass
{
    private string _a, _b;

    public myClass(string args)
    {
        _a = args.Split(',')[0];
        _b = args.Split(',')[1];
    }

    public string A { get { return _a; } set { _a = value; } }
    public string B { get { return _b; } set { _b = value; } }
    //and so on
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i will be trying this and getting back to you as best i can

Answer (score 0):

```
 public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }

    public Sample(string strSplit) {
        var values = strSplit.Split(',');
        A = values[0];
        B = values[1];
    }
Sample dd = new Sample("James,Jonathan");
```

better use reflection

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i will be trying this and getting back to you as best i can